# How can I draw multiple trendlines for scatterplots with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, economics

I'm trying to draw a plot for a basic difference-in-differences implementation (for those who have studied economics might be familiar to you). So I have two separate time series which cover the years 2015-2019. I'd like two draw a trendline for both time series. The problem is I have two draw for each time series two trendlines. The first covers 1/2015-7/2017 and the second should cover 8/2017-12/2019. I have managed to draw lines by using geom_smooth followingly:

```
    ggplot()+
      geom_line(data=timeseries2,aes(x=month,y=price_mean),color="red", size=1)+
      geom_line(data=timeseries1,aes(x=month,y=price_mean), color="dodgerblue4", size=1)+
      geom_smooth(data=timeseries2,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color=time),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
      geom_smooth(data=timeseries1,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color=time),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
      theme_classic()+
      labs(x="Month",y="Price")+
      geom_vline(xintercept =data1$month[32],linetype="dashed")
```

This is the results of the code above:
[image]

The first problem here is that I'dont need a Before/After legend and I'd like to replace it with a Timeseries1/Timeseries2 legend. The second problem is the colours of the geom_smooth trend lines. I'd like that the timeseries1 scatterplot has the same colour but individual trendlines for both before and after conditions. The same applies to the other timeseries. Now the colours are same depending on time not the timeseries in use.

Comment: was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I have created three kinds of plot(I think the second one is what you meant)

**First Plot:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Timeseries simulation
timeseries1 <- data.frame(
  month = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2019/12/1"), by = "month"),
  price_mean = sample(100:300, 60, replace = FALSE)
)

timeseries2 <- data.frame(
  month = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2019/12/1"), by = "month"),
  price_mean = sample(300:600, 60, replace = FALSE)
)

data1 <- rbind(timeseries1, timeseries2)

# dividing timeseries into two parts
timeseries1_B <- timeseries1 %>%
  filter(month >= as.Date(data1$month[32]))

timeseries1_A <- timeseries1 %>%
  filter(month <= as.Date(data1$month[32]))

timeseries2_B <- timeseries2 %>%
  filter(month >= as.Date(data1$month[32]))

timeseries2_A <- timeseries2 %>%
  filter(month <= as.Date(data1$month[32]))

#First plot
ggplot(data = timeseries1, aes(x = month, y = price_mean))+
  geom_line(data=timeseries1_A, color="dodgerblue4", size=1) + 
  geom_line(data = timeseries2_A, color = "dodgerblue4", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(data=timeseries1_B, color="red", size=1) + 
  geom_line(data = timeseries2_B, color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries1_A,aes(x=month,y=price_mean, color = "dodgerblue4"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries2_A,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color="dodgerblue4"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries1_B,aes(x=month,y=price_mean, color = "red"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries2_B,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color="red"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Month",y="Price")+
  geom_vline(xintercept =data1$month[32],linetype="dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Time", labels = c("Timeseries1", "timeseries2"), values = c("dodgerblue4","red"))
```

[image]

**Second plot:**

```
#the same code as above then ...

#second plot:  
  
ggplot(data = timeseries1, aes(x = month, y = price_mean))+
  geom_line(data=timeseries1_A, color="dodgerblue4", size=1) + 
  geom_line(data = timeseries2_A, color = "red", size = 1) + 
  geom_line(data=timeseries1_B, color="dodgerblue4", size=1) + 
  geom_line(data = timeseries2_B, color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries1_A,aes(x=month,y=price_mean, color = "dodgerblue4"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries2_A,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color="red"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries1_B,aes(x=month,y=price_mean, color = "dodgerblue4"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries2_B,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color="red"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Month",y="Price")+
  geom_vline(xintercept =data1$month[32],linetype="dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Time", labels = c("Timeseries1", "Timeseries2"), values = c("dodgerblue4","red"))
```

[image]

**Third Plot**

```
# Timeseires simulation
timeseries1 <- data.frame(
  month = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2019/12/1"), by = "month"),
  price_mean = sample(100:300, 60, replace = FALSE)
)

timeseries2 <- data.frame(
  month = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2019/12/1"), by = "month"),
  price_mean = sample(300:600, 60, replace = FALSE)
)


data1 <- rbind(timeseries1, timeseries2)


ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=timeseries2,aes(x=month,y=price_mean),color="red", size=1)+
  geom_line(data=timeseries1,aes(x=month,y=price_mean), color="dodgerblue4", size=1)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries2,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color="red"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=timeseries1,aes(x=month,y=price_mean,color="dodgerblue4"),method=lm,se=FALSE)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Month",y="Price")+
  geom_vline(xintercept =data1$month[32],linetype="dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Time", labels = c("Timeseries1", "timeseries2"), values = c("dodgerblue4","red"))
```

it creates something like this:
[image]